# Erlang - why is a new process being created

Tags: process, erlang, pid

well I am trying to create a counter, using code found here

```
-module(counter).
-export([start/0,loop/1,increment/1,value/1,stop/1]).

%% First the interface functions.

start() ->
    spawn(counter, loop, [0]).

increment(Counter) ->
    Counter ! increment.

value(Counter) ->
    Counter ! {self(),value},
    receive
          {Counter,Value} ->
                            Value
    end.

stop(Counter) ->
    Counter ! stop.

%% The counter loop.

loop(Val) ->
           receive
               increment ->
                           loop(Val + 1);
               {From,value} ->
                           From ! {self(),Val},
                           loop(Val);
                stop -> % No recursive call here
                        true;
                Other -> % All other messages
                        loop(Val)
            end.
```

The code I am using in my module is (for testing purposes only, since I can't figure out why it is doing this):

```
test3() ->
    Counter = counter:start().
```

So whenever I run test3, it creates a NEW counter process with a NEW pid. Why is this? I am just trying to have a single counter

Answer (score 0):

It is common technique in testing, especially in [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing), known as [fixture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_fixture). Fixture is way how to test some stateful code (as counters in your case) from known state. It is init state in this case.

Answer (score 0):

What else do you expect? counter:start() is going to launch a new process every time you call it.

```
start() ->
    spawn(counter, loop, [0]).
```

You might want to use: [register/2](http://erldocs.com/R16B02/erts/erlang.html?i=0&search=register#register/2)

Comment: But when I assign a process id to Counter, shouldn't it throw up an error the next time I assign Counter a different PID? I didn't think that was possible. I am clearly misunderstanding things here

I have tried using register also, but then when I register it as something/anything (for example: bread) it no longer seems to function. I cannot call: counter:increment(bread). , it just gets stuck.

Comment: So I could use, register(bread, counter:start())

And then to increment it, use something like: bread ! increment. IN this case

Answer (score 0):

Erlang's `spawn` functions create processes (See the doc: http://erldocs.com/R16B02/erts/erlang.html?i=2&search=spawn#spawn/3)

If you want to identify uniquely your counter-server, you may have a look at [register](http://erldocs.com/R16B02/erts/erlang.html?i=0&search=register#register/2). It will enable you to bind a pid to an atom and then use this atom in your messages instead of the pid.

Comment: I have used register to bind the counter pid to the atom bread. But now I am unsure about how to actually use the registered name. Sending messages in the form: bread ! increment does not seem to work, and I can no longer use counter:increment(bread)

Comment: Use the registered name as a pid. Here:
`true = erlang:register(shell, self()), shell ! hello, flush().`